# Displaying Image in Image Control vs Grid/Canvas Background

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, grid

It seems there is some redundancy in WPF when it comes to displaying of an image.

In my current application, it looks like I can either:

- Use the `ImageControl`.
- Use a `Grid` (within a Grid) and set the `Grid.Background` property.
- Use `Canvas` and set the `Background` Property.

It seems most controls have a background property.

One section of a current program I am working on uses an image control to preview photos from the hard drive. Are their advantages/disadvantages to using the image control vs some of the other controls?

Comment: It doesn't matter much if you use an Image control or an ImageBrush in the Background (or Fill) of some other element. The Image control is easier to use in most situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display an image you should use an image object, example XAML code...

```
 <Image Width="250" Height="100" Source="Resources/logo.png"/>
```

Grids are not designed to simply contain an image, instead they are a type of layout panel and used to contain other items. For more information [see here.](https://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Canvas again are not designed for that purpose, instead they are also a type of layout panel commonly used to contain graphics, such as polygons. For more information [see here.](https://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html)

The advantages and disadvantages, is simply your using an element for a purpose it's not designed for. You should use the appropriate element for proper coding practices.

**EDIT** If you'd like to overlay shapes on top of an image then a canvas would be more appropriate. See code below...

```
 <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="115,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images.jpg"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="66" Canvas.Left="135" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="108" Width="60"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="80" Canvas.Left="10" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="18" Width="84"/>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: So if I was creating a program to draw a selection rectangle over the top of an image, the Image Control would still be better than Canvas?

Comment: In a situation like that, no a canvas would be more appropriate and you would want to change the canvas background because the canvas is a type of layout panel which you can draw the rectangles onto. See code above^

Comment: Apologies, you can probably tell I'm new to answering questions.